# Change action respond_to depending on response code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following `create` action:

```
def create

  @report = Report.new(params[:report])
  @file = params[:report][:data_file]


  res = @report.get_report(@file, @report.year, @report.month)

  file = open('report.pdf','wb')
  file.write(res.body)

  @report.file = file

  respond_to do |format|
    if @report.save
      format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @report, status: :created, location: @report }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

end
```

However the HTTP response stored in the `res` variable can have a `200` code, or a `400` code that indicates a Bad Request. I want that if the `res.code` is 400, it also goes back to the `new` action with a warning message.

I tried including that condition on the respond_to if like below, but it didn't worked. It seems that after creating the instance it redirected to `edit` action. It makes no sense.

```
  respond_to do |format|
    if @report.save and res.code == 200
      format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @report, status: :created, location: @report }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Add the rails console log to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a complicated workflow, but it looks like if res's status is 400, you just want to render the new form again. So you can early escape using the below:

```
  if res.status != 200
    render :new
    return
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @report.save
      format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @report, status: :created, location: @report }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```